# How to execute tests in postman based on IF condition

Tags: postman

I want to exeucute Tests script in postman based on IF condition. 
for eg:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
 if(responseCode.code === 404 ){
    tests["TEst1: Invalid ID passed"];
  }
```

When I use the above one it is not executing. How to use if condition on tests

Comment: You do not need the if condition here, just write: `tests["Status code is 404"] = responseCode.code === 404;`

Answer (score -1):

To test the response code, you can do it directly.

```
tests["Status code is 400"] = responseCode.code === 400;
```

You have to use below line when you want to test the data inside the Json.

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Success --> Request & Response account first name matched"] = data.firstName === postman.getEnvironmentVariable("firstName");
```

Comment: This did not answer how to use an if conditional.